# vs code extension: how to set the icon status in activity bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I added some buttons in the activity bar in VSCode, but haven't found a way to disable/enable them. Does anybody know how to do that?

[image: Disable or enable the icons in the activity bar]

Answer (score 0):

U can edit whatever you need in your setting.json file.

For example:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {      
    "editorCursor.foreground": "#00FFFF",
    "statusBar.background": "#242526",
    "statusBar.foreground": "#696969",
    "activityBar.background": "#242526",
    "activityBar.foreground": "#696969"
},
```

Comment: I mean change its status programmably, to be disable or enable, instead of its color.